# MYSQL Select JOIN from temporary tables inside stored procedures not working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, inner-join, sql-insert

I am facing a problem with a select join inside a stored procedure. In the procedure I create two temporary table K1 and K2 which share a common key (t_id). Each one have just one value column. What I want to do is to join both tables to retrieve a table with the key and two columns with the values.

The K1 table is something like this

```
--------------
t_id | KPI1
--------------
1     0.5
2     0.3
3     0.7
--------------
```

The K2 table is something like this

```
--------------
t_id | KPI2
--------------
1     0.4
2     0.2
3     0.1
--------------
```

The expecte result is this:

```
--------------------
t_id | KPI1 | KPI2
--------------------
1     0.5    0.4
2     0.3    0.2
3     0.7    0.1
--------------------
```

If I run this code in a regular query it works perfectly:

```
set @t_ini = '2020-07-01 00:00:00';
set @t_end = '2020-07-04 00:00:00';
create temporary table K12 (t_id int,KPI1 float, KPI2 float);

-- get KPI1 in a temporary table
create temporary table K1 as 
select distinct intervaldate.ID as t_id,Value as KPI1
from 
kpi_db,intervaldate,controllers
where 
kpi_db.Interval_ID = intervaldate.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = controllers.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = CtrlID and 
intervaldate.TStart between  @t_ini and @t_end and
kpi_db.KPI_ID = 1;
-- get KPI2 in a temporary table
create temporary table K2 as 
select distinct distinct intervaldate.ID as t_id,Value as KPI2
from 
kpi_db,intervaldate,controllers
where 
kpi_db.Interval_ID = intervaldate.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = controllers.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = CtrlID and 
intervaldate.TStart between @t_ini and @t_end and
kpi_db.KPI_ID = 2;
-- merge the two temporary tables
insert into K12(t_id,KPI1,KPI2)
select K1.t_id,KPI1,KPI2
from K1
left join
K2
on (K1.t_id = K2.t_id);

select * from K12;
```

but when I put this inside a store procedure the K12 returns just null values

```
--------------------
t_id | KPI1 | KPI2
--------------------
1     Null    Null
2     Null    Null
3     Null    Null
--------------------
```

The stored procedure is the following

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateKPIs1_2`(CtrlID int,EventID int,PCT float)
BEGIN
declare done int default 0;
declare t_ini datetime;
declare t_end datetime;
declare t_id int;
declare kpi1 float;
declare kpi2 float;
declare kpi1_nc float;
declare kpi1_new float;
-- cursors declaration
declare cursor_KPIs cursor for select * from K12;
declare continue  handler for not found set done = true;
-- temporary table declaration
create temporary table K12 (t_id int,KPI1 float, KPI2 float);
-- select t_ini and t_end
set t_ini = date((select Turn_OFF from turn_on_off where ID = EventID));
set t_end = date((select Turn_ON from turn_on_off where ID = EventID));
-- get KPI1 in a temporary table
create temporary table K1 as 
select distinct intervaldate.ID as t_id,Value as KPI1
from 
kpi_db,intervaldate,controllers
where 
kpi_db.Interval_ID = intervaldate.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = controllers.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = CtrlID and 
intervaldate.TStart between  t_ini and t_end and
kpi_db.KPI_ID = 1;
-- get KPI2 in a temporary table
create temporary table K2 as 
select distinct distinct intervaldate.ID as t_id,Value as KPI2
from 
kpi_db,intervaldate,controllers
where 
kpi_db.Interval_ID = intervaldate.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = controllers.ID and 
kpi_db.Ctrl_ID = CtrlID and 
intervaldate.TStart between t_ini and t_end and
kpi_db.KPI_ID = 2;
-- merge the two temporary tables
insert into K12(t_id,KPI1,KPI2)
select K1.t_id,KPI1,KPI2
from K1
left join
K2
on (K1.t_id = K2.t_id);
-- iterate over the K12 temporary table
open cursor_KPIs;

select * from K1;
select * from K2;
select * from K12;

-- HERE COMES SOME PROCESSING USING THE CURSOR. I droped it
-- to make the script more clear.

drop table K1;
drop table K2;
drop table K12;
-- close cursor
close cursor_KPIs;
END
```

I wonder if this problem has something to do with delimiters but I am not getting how to set up delimiters properly here.

I think that I am doing something really silly here but I can't see it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really looks like you are overcomplicating things here:

- both queries are almost identical - only the `where` clauses differ - you could get the same result in a single query, using conditional aggregation
- I don't see the point for the temporary tables; you can insert in the target table directly from the result of the query

I think something like this should be rather close to what you want:

```
insert into k12(t_id, kpi1, kpi2)
select 
    i.id as t_id, 
    max(case when k.kpi_id = 1 then k.value end) as kpi1,
    max(case when k.kpi_id = 2 then k.value end) as kpi2
from kpi_db k
inner join intervaldate i on k.interval_id = i.id
inner join controllers c on k.ctrl_id = c.id 
where i.tstart between @t_ini and @t_end and k.kpi_id in (1, 2)
group by i.id;
```

Comment: I run the code above but it return a table with all values as 1.

Comment: I managed to make it work. There is a aditional where clause that was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thread!

I wonder if it is possible to generate a temp table in a function/procedure that can subsequently be used to join in an expression like e.g.

(Syntaxcheck off!)

```
FUNCTION CreateTS(DATETIME from, DATETIME to, INT intervalSec) 
BEGIN
    -- create temp table having records 
    -- 1,(from, from+intervalSec),
    -- 2,(from+intervalSec,from+intervalSec*2),
    -- ...,
    -- n,(to-intervalSec,to)
    return resultset 
END
```

to be used in queries like

```
SELECT ts.from,ts.to,(some aggregating expression based on t1) 
FROM CreateTS(DATE_SUB(NOW(),30,day),NOW(),3600) ts 
JOIN T1 t1 on t1.datetime >= ts.from AND t1.datetime < ts.to
```

Ideally SQL had a virtual timescale table that could be used as

```
SELECT * FROM timescale ts WHERE ts.from >= ... and ts.to < ... and ts.type = week
```

where type could be all the normal second,minute,hour,day,week,month,year

so above example could be

```
SELECT ts.from,ts.to,(some aggregating expression based on t1) 
FROM TS ts 
JOIN T1 t1 on t1.datetime >= ts.from AND t1.datetime < ts.to
WHERE ts.from = DATE_SUB(NOW(),30,day) and ts.to = NOW() and ts.type=hour
```

Thanks